# MySQL query ignoring capitalization

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing password and username login query and it looks like this

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
```

I pass in my username and password.  The problem is that say i have a username 'user' and their password it 'password'.  When i type in 'user' and 'Password' into the fields it return with a result still.  So that makes capitals useless.  Am i doing something wrong? is there a better way to go about this?  The capital problem is the same for the username.  Its like it is doing a patter match when i want an exact string match.  I have tried binary as well in hopes that it might have changed it but same results.

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: how do you pass your variables to this query? And what is the type of your tables?

Comment: Password should be hashed (and salted) in which case the hash case would not matter, but the hash would only be generated by a password of the correct case.

Comment: What is the collation of `users`?

Comment: do you have any links on a how to or information about hashing and salting passwords appropriately? i know what it is i just dont know how to do it.

Comment: are you refering to data type of my password and username columns? if so they are varchar

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial on the hows and whys of the hash and salt technique [net.tutsplus.com](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html):

> Simple comparison operations (>=, >, =, <, <=, sorting, and grouping) are based on each character's “sort value.” Characters with the same sort value are treated as the same character. For example, if “e” and “é” have the same sort value in a given collation, they compare as equal.
>
> The default character set and collation are latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string comparisons are case insensitive by default. This means that if you search with col_name LIKE 'a%', you get all column values that start with A or a. To make this search case sensitive, make sure that one of the operands has a case sensitive or binary collation. For example, if you are comparing a column and a string that both have the latin1 character set, you can use the COLLATE operator to cause either operand to have the latin1_general_cs or latin1_bin collation:

You should change the collation of your table or columns to something that is case sensitive or use a binary collation.

Answer (score 2):

That's a typical collation problem.
Default collations compare case insensitive. You should use a binary collation for the compare.

default utf8 collation

```
mysql> SELECT 'password' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci = 'PASSWORD' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 'password' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci = 'PASSWORD' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                       1 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

utf8 binary collation

```
mysql> SELECT 'password' COLLATE utf8_bin = 'PASSWORD' COLLATE utf8_bin;
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 'password' COLLATE utf8_bin = 'PASSWORD' COLLATE utf8_bin |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                         0 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'password' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci = 'password' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 'password' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci = 'password' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                       1 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Change your query to

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password COLLATE utf8_bin = ?";
```

read more about collations here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-general.html

Answer (score 2):

What collation are you using? [see here for information on case sensitivity in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html)

You should probably be using a binary collation for usernames and password columns either way.

Notably:

> To make this search case sensitive, make sure that one of the operands has a case sensitive or binary collation.

also

> If you want a column always to be treated in case-sensitive fashion, declare it with a case sensitive or binary collation. See Section 13.1.10, “CREATE TABLE Syntax”.

Also, ideally, you should be salting and hashing your passwords at a minimum. You then salt and hash the user supplied password at login when doing the comparison. Storing plaintext passwords is bad practice and should be avoided.